# Is it possible to create a post from an NextGen Gallery image? [WORDPRESS]

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields, nextgen-gallery

I have uploaded many pictures, and I would like to create a new post for each of them with a specific category named `photos` and a custom field `url` with the url of the image.

Is that possible ?

I imagine a button `Create Post` in the NextGen interface next to `View / Edit / Delete` links

Do you know if there are a plugin or something like that ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a plugin for this.

1. Create a New Post
2. Set type to image
3. Upload the image here from NextGEN if required
4. Specify Category as `photos`
5. Add `url` of the image into custom field
6. Done

This has a lot of advantages, allowing you to perform all operations available to posts by default like searches.

See screenshot of how I set it up.

[image]

Cheers